# CSS3 Content Slider cuts content off

Tags: css

I've created a content slider in CSS3 for images. I wanted to create a pure CSS3 slider, without any Javascript or JQuery. However, my images are somehow "cut off".

**You can see the problem live [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/thHpE).**

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
<img src="1.jpg" /><img src="1.jpg" /><img src="1.jpg" /><img src="1.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#slider
{
    height: 200px;  
    width: 500px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;  
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: left .3s linear;
    -moz-transition: left .3s linear;
    -o-transition: left .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: left .3s linear;
    -webkit-animation: slide-animation 25s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-animation {
    0% {left:0px; opacity:1;}
    20% {left:0px; opacity:1;}
    25% {left:-500px; opacity:1;}
    45% {left:-500px; opacity:1;}
    50% {left:-1000px; opacity:1;}
    70% {left:-1000px; opacity:1;}
    75% {left:-1500px; opacity:1;}
    100% {left:-1500px; opacity:0;}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your container has a width that is not enough to hold all the images.

When you move it to the left, the right border of the container enters in the view, and the images can not be seen.

Another way to achieve this can be changing the margin of the first of the images.

[updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wnulc)

CSS

```
#slider img:first-child {
    -webkit-animation: slide-animation 25s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-animation {
    0% {margin-left:0px; opacity:1;}
    20% {margin-left:0px; opacity:1;}
    25% {margin-left:-500px; opacity:1;}
    45% {margin-left:-500px; opacity:1;}
    50% {margin-left:-1000px; opacity:1;}
    70% {margin-left:-1000px; opacity:1;}
    75% {margin-left:-1500px; opacity:1;}
    100% {margin-left:-1500px; opacity:0;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the `width` and `height` of the images corresponding to their container.

```
img{


  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Well, with that the full image shows.

**Update:**

as your container has a `width:700px` so your `animation keyframes` should be,

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide-animation {
        0% {margin-left:0px; opacity:1;}
        20% {margin-left:0px; opacity:1;}
        25% {margin-left:-700px; opacity:1;}
        45% {margin-left:-700px; opacity:1;}
        50% {margin-left:-1400px; opacity:1;}
        70% {margin-left:-1400px; opacity:1;}
        75% {margin-left:-2100px; opacity:1;}
        100% {margin-left:-2100px; opacity:0;}
    }
```

updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhFWd/3/).

Comment: Check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/bhFWd/ , the complete image is being shown.

Answer (score 0):

Set the total width of all the images to the width of the container.

```
    #slider
    {
    width:1500px; 
    }
```

Comment: That's an option, but I would like the upcoming image to be invisible until it appears, so this isn't really an option then.